# Pass id int into query

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a query where I pass by parameters the `groupID`, but the query does not recognize the number`(group id)`.All the values are reaching the query( I debugged). This is my query, can you see if the structure is ok?

```
public Cursor updateGrupo(String nomegrupo,int idgroup){
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
//Does not put the ID in the "idgroup"
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("UPDATE  '"+tableGrupo+"' SET '"+nomeGrupo+"' = '"+nomegrupo+"' WHERE '"+idGrupo+"' = '"+idgroup+"'", new String[]{});
return c;
}
```

Comment: This is not how you do it. Use Prepared Statements

Comment: @juergend it's a raw qry not prepared statement, i don't say it's a good way to this , but to clear the situation :)

Comment: So? Raw queries support Prepared Statements.

Comment: yes, you are right, i totally missed that!

Comment: Can you put an example below?

Comment: @juergend A prepared statement would be created with [compileStatement()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement(java.lang.String)). This problem calls for parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use `SQLiteDatabase` as writable mode `getWritableDatabase()`.
2. You should use below method for updating data:

   update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)

**Try this:**

```
public void updateGrupo(String nomegrupo,int idgroup) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
    values.put(nomeGrupo, nomegrupo);

    db.update(tableGrupo, values, idGrupo + " = ? " , new String[]{String.valueOf(idgroup)});
}
```

Comment: I forgot to change the getReadableDatabase. Thank you very much